# Barnard's unconditional test gives different results when switching rows and columns?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, contingency-tables

I'm really new to statistical analysis, and I've been playing around with exact tests for 2x2 contingency tables. I've noticed that for the Barnard test (implementation with `library(Barnard)` in R) gives different results depending on how the contingency table is organized as shown below in the two images.

Can anyone explain why this type of behavior occurs? I know this doesn't happen for Fisher Exact Test, so I was wondering why it happens for Barnard's Unconditional Test...

[image]

[image]

Comment: As the printout explains, the hypothesis behind the implemented test is that *columns* are the same. Your first comparison is 158 vs. 149, the second 4 vs. 303.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisher's exact test conditions on both margins, so, the results are the same for either order. Barnard's test conditions on one margin, and thus the results are not the same.  That is, the margins in one direction are fixed, in the other direction, they are unconstrained.

The implementation in R tests differences in the columns (see the help page for barnard.test).